# Typescript: return type of generic type

Tags: typescript

I need to translate this java concept:

```
public interface Expression<T> {
  Class<? extends T> getType();
}
```

Is there any way to get it or something similar?

Comment: javascript type system does not have a "Class" type so there is no equivalent of Class<T>.

Could you please provide more context and tell us how getType would be used?

Comment: What I want to get is only to return the type if T...

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you have typeof operator. For example, typeof "Jon" will return "string". In your case, typeof function getType(){} will return "function"

Answer (score 0):

Like @savinn mentioned, there is the `typeof` operator which returns a `string` representation, but [you can also access the `.constructor` member as well](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor).

The caveats are

1. that this only gives you the constructor function, but generics aren't preserved in any way, so you'll likely get `Array` from a `number[]`, but no information about the element type `number` will be available.
2. It might not give you what you want for primitives:

   `$> 123 instanceof (123).constructor
   $< false
   $> new Number(123) instanceof (123).constructor
   $< true`